# What would be a good way to show this data?

Tags: kendo-mobile, telerik-appbuilder

What would be the best way to show this in on a mobile app that could be run on different screen sizes ? I am not really looking for a design as much as an idea of what mark up I could use to display this information.

```
 Description    Quanity   Price    Total

 Car               3       $5,000  $15,000
 Bike              4       $100    $400
 5 feet of string  4       $800    $1600 
 5 feet of gum     4       $800    $1600 
                         **Total:  $18,600
```

coming from a non mobile world I would use a table or a Kendo Grid but mobile doesn't seem to provide these or I don't know how I would use them properly. My biggest thing is variable length of the description column

Comment: Rob if you want to put that as a answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a Kendo UI Grid (it's fully responsive), but you'll have to leverage Kendo UI Pro which is not available as part of a base Telerik Platform subscription. You can look at the pricing details here to see which licenses come with the full Kendo UI Web.

Answer (score 1):

if it's just a table, you can use bootstrap. Kendo Grid, will just offer a scroll bar for large tables and this can be done with bootstrap. Review some of the open source css frameworks and see which one works best for your project.